# Migration back?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

Recently I posted a question about preventing deer damage.  It was migrated to Gardening.

I considered that SE site when posting, but realized that my question was mostly about deer behaviour, and not about plants.  Hence I choose biology.SE

The question, now on Gardening

https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/46295/can-a-mix-of-a-sticking-agent-and-a-bitter-salt-be-used-to-deter-deer-and-moose

Comment: I don't see how your question is about deer behavior. I think migration was correct. I think you will not get an answer here, you might get an answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the gardening mods **before** moving the question, as I think you will most likely not get an answer here. They agreed that it would fit their site, So no, I don't think it will be moved back.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the feedback.